# Bundle adjuster outputs

Tags: opencv

I am using the Parallell Bundle Adjuster library as a step in a Structure From Motion project (using OpenCV).
However, when I run the bundle adjuster, the camera matrices (both position and translation) seem to get a lot worse (the points seem fine, though). Additionally, the Bundle adjuster reports a much higher mean square error than I anticipate (10^6), but ends up with a low error, so I suspect the initial conditions are wrong somehow.

With bundle adjust: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixG3M.jpg
Without bundle adjust: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp8mU.jpg
(The lines indicate camera direction)

Does anyone know any good way to debug the Parallell Bundle Adjuster?

Comment: Too much code, please reduce to MWE showing your problem. Else it is going to be downvoted. What's the question, anyway ?